# How to manipulate {someprops.somevalue} and turn the spaces into '-'?

Tags: reactjs, string, react-router, react-props

There is this function-

```
const ficcards=({posts})=> (
{posts.map(post => (
      <div key={post.id} className="FicCards">
        <h2>{post.FicName}</h2>
        <p className="fic-description">{post.description} 
        </p>
      </div>
    ))}
)
```

What I want to do is that use  component to give them a direct link plus change all the spaces in FicName to '-'.

In past i simply did `const ficURL = FicName.replace(/\s/g, '-');` and then simply do a 
`<Link to={ficURL}></Link>`
when i had hard coded values, any way to pick the corrent values from `{post.FicName}` ?

Comment: propsName.value isn't in your code

Comment: Does `<Link to={(post.FicName).replace(/\s/g, '-')}><Link>` work?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was a rather silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

`Does <Link to={(post.FicName).replace(/\s/g, '-')}><Link>`

Doing this worked. Closing it